libVLC volume difference compared to other media players
I am using libVLC in my project to support some additional audio and video files.
Thereby, I found that the audible volume differs compared to other media players when using low volume and libVLC.
This is also true for normal VLC Media Player.
Questions:

Which formula does VLC volume (0 to 100) use?
How to set the VLC volume such that the output volume on the speakers is like other media players?

Steps to reproduce:

Play an audio file in Windows Media Player, AIMP, and normal VLC, where each media player is set to 20% volume.
Listen to the audio output.

VLC is much more quiet compared to the others.



